# Coloring conditional plot line

Tags: conditional-statements, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm struggling with conditional coloring of a line when using `request.security function`.

I'm trying to calculate the slope value for `zerolagEMA_2` and color the line accordingly. However it only plots the line as black, probably meaning the conditions are not met under any circumstances

```
// Calculate the ZLEMA slope using the formula
  x = input.int(title="Range", minval=1, defval=5)
  dynamicLength = int(x * (request.security(syminfo.tickerid, selectedTimeframe, close) / close))
  y = ZerolagEMA_2 - ta.sma(ZerolagEMA_2, dynamicLength)
 angle = math.atan(y / x)

// Convert the angle from radians to degrees
 angleDegree = angle * (180 / 3.14159265359)  // Multiply by (180 / π)

// Define the color based on the angle and threshold
 angleColor = angleDegree > AngleThreshold ? color.green : angleDegree < -AngleThreshold ?    color.red : color.black

plot(ZerolagEMA_1, color=color.blue, linewidth=3, title="ZLEMA1")
plot(ZerolagEMA_3, color=color.blue, linewidth=3, title="ZLEMA3")
plot(ZerolagEMA_2, color=angleColor, linewidth=4, title="ZLEMA2")
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated..

trying to achieve this

[image]

but this is what I get:

[image]